# "Error Executing Command, Exiting" Error upon installation of NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04LTS.
I typed in the following command in the terminal:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
```

In return, I am receiving the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

I just installed the very old version of NodeJS and NPM from the Ubuntu repositories because I could not install the most current version. However, I still want the most current version of Node and NPM.

Comment: `npm i -g npm` updates npm. For Node check [`n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)

Comment: Did you have update your package list with `sudo apt update` before run the command ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I performed an update

Comment: I think your problem does not come from the node installer but a wrong package in your package list: seems to be the package `http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu`.

Comment: How do I remove it?

Comment: Update: I removed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. The problem is not the `nodejs` installation script but another package in your package list in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

The following worked for me:

1) Create backup of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` just to be on the safe side:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bu
```

2) Remove the packages that cause the issue:
Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` with root permissions, e.g.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and remove the

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
```

parts. In my case it was skype that caused the issue; you can identify the critical packages by the lines that start with `E: Failed to fetch`.

Afterwards, the following works fine (taken from the [installation instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04)):

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

If one then types

```
nodejs -v
```

it will return

```
v8.9.4
```

(or whatever version you specified).

In case you already have [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux) installed, I recommend to install `node.js` inside an environment which keeps things clean. A detailed explanation on how to do this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51557141/install-nodejs-inside-conda-environment). Basically all it needs is

```
conda create -n webdev nodejs
```

plus desired python modules in case you would like to use e.g. `Flask` or `Django`.