# Install nodeJS inside conda environment

Tags: node.js, virtualenv, conda, package-managers

I want to use NodeJS and AngularJS for a small project.

Can I use conda's virtualenv to install these packages inside a separate virtual environment, and then have them removed from the system once I delete the virtualenv?

Comment: You might want to look into Node version managers for that. [nvs](https://github.com/jasongin/nvs/blob/master/doc/SETUP.md) can be installed into a custom location (such as your virtualenv or project directory)

Comment: Thx, so, installing Node inside a conda virtualenv is the same as installing it on the system? It wont be removed if I delete the virtual env?

Comment: I haven't tried it TBH, but nvs gets installed in home directory by default. So deleting the virtualenv shouldn't affect it.

Comment: Okay, thx for the help

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can for sure use conda to create virtual environments for nodejs programs.

```
$ conda create -yn myapp nodejs
$ conda activate myapp
$ node --version
v8.11.3
$ npm --version
5.6.0
```

And then in the environment `myapp`, you can do all of your app development and once you are done, removal is also easy:

```
$ conda env remove -yn myapp
```

Instead of environments, you can also use prefixes. Like:

```
$ conda create -yp ./myapp nodejs
$ conda activate ./myapp
$ node --version
v8.11.3
$ npm --version
5.6.0
```

And once you are done, just delete it.

```
$ conda env remove -yp ./myapp
```

OR

```
$ rm -fr ./myapp
```

Comment: Spread the word! Conda is *not* tied to python, except the fact that it was written in python.

Comment: @FakherMokadem: Please accept the answer as it solved your problem :)

Comment: I did, sorry for missing that.

Comment: Then if I run `npm install -g X` in the conda env, will the global package X be in the conda env too? Are there related docs on "behavior of other package managers in conda env"?

Comment: `npm install -g X` will install `X` in `/path/to/conda-environment-for-nodejs/lib/node_modules/X`

Comment: @NehalJWani I can't get this to work. For some reason in my environment the system node is default and npm install -g X installs to system module path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69020379/nodejs-anaconda-and-setting-nodepath