# NodeJS, Anaconda and setting NodePath (conda not updating paths)

Tags: python, node.js, anaconda

I've installed NodeJS in Anaconda with

```
conda install -c anaconda nodejs
```

but I cannot install anything globally. If I run

```
npm install -g <some package>
```

I get a permissions error since it seems to be trying to save modules to the default location. If I look in the environment I can see the node_modules folder there so it seems to me that the `NODE_PATH` variable is not being set. I can do this manually for the environment but it seems to me that I shouldn't need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't specific to nodejs but also affecting python. Turns out although the environment was loaded I needed to run

```
conda activate base
```

as specified here

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

Seems to be related to this bug:

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9392